# What may happen after a stack of spells resolves?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Within the same phase, once a stack of spells has resolved in its entirety, is priority once again given to a player so that more spells may be cast?

For example:

I attack with a creature. Opponent opts not to block. Now, I want to buff (e.g. +3/+3) my creature multiple times, but I'm afraid of my opponent responding with a burn (e.g. Deal 3 damage) spell at the top of the stack. Can I buff once, ask if opponent wants to respond, then allow the stack to resolve. Then, in the same phase, cast more buff?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The active player (whose turn it is) receives priority after any spell or ability resolves**

If that player passes, every other player in turn order gets priority as regular, and everyone with priority can cast spells or abilities, including when the last item on the stack resolves.

From the comprehensive rules:

> 116.3. Which player has priority is determined by the following rules:
>
> 116.3a The active player receives priority at the beginning of most steps and phases, after any turn-based actions (such as drawing a card during the draw step; see rule 703) have been dealt with and abilities that trigger at the beginning of that phase or step have been put on the stack. No player receives priority during the untap step. Players usually don’t get priority during the cleanup step (see rule 514.3).
>
> **116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.**
>
> 116.3c If a player has priority when he or she casts a spell, activates an ability, or takes a special action, that player receives priority afterward.
>
> 116.3d If a player has priority and chooses not to take any actions, that player passes. If any mana is in that player’s mana pool, he or she announces what mana is there. Then the next player in turn order receives priority.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the active Player receives priority after a spell or ability resolves, and the next phase does not occur until both players pass priority when the stack is empty.

> 116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.
>
> 500.2. A phase or step in which players receive priority ends when the stack is empty and all players pass in succession. **Simply having the stack become empty doesn't cause such a phase or step to end; all players have to pass in succession with the stack empty**. Because of this, each player gets a chance to add new things to the stack before that phase or step ends.